# Changing text to icons when a media query is met

Tags: html, css

I'm making a website where the text changes to icons when the resolution hits 640px or less. I was wondering if there is a way I can implement this using CSS, or is this more complicated and should use JQuery or something like this?

Here is a visual representation of what I want to do:

Before the media query is met:
http://4.ii.gl/mkcrfiLzq.png

After the media query:
http://1.ii.gl/yed0kk0t6.png

Any help will be highly appreciated and the neatest solution will be rewarded with the answer.

```
<div>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a><img src="images/LOGO.svg" height="44px" alt="Sandwich Express"/></a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home<a></li>
            <li><a href="whatwedo.html">What We Do<a></li>
            <li><a href="oursandwiches">Our Sandwiches<a></li>
            <li><a href="contactus">Contact Us<a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

This is the HTML of the banner I'd like to change, and the CSS that pairs with this is:

```
 nav ul li a {
     display: block;
     margin-left: -40px;
     font-size: 20px;
     line-height: 44px;
     font-family: "Josefin Sans";
     text-align: center;
     text-decoration: none;
     color: white;
     padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
     background-color: black;
     -o-transition: .5s;
     -ms-transition: .5s;
     -moz-transition: .5s;
     -webkit-transition: .5s;
     transition: .5s;
}
 nav ul li a:hover {
     color: #CFCFCF;
}
```

Any other code needed I'll post.

Comment: You *can* with CSS, but you haven't included any code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try it like this:

HTML

```
<div>
    <span class="text">text</span>
    <span class="icon"><img src="" /></span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
@media (min-width: 641px) {
    span.icon {display:none}
    span.text {display:inline-block}
}

@media (max-width: 640px) {
    span.icon {display:inline-block}
    span.text {display:none}
}
```

**EDIT (CODEPEN EXAMPLE)**

Have a look at this working example [CodePen](http://codepen.io/giannisKapa/pen/wBaPwe)

Comment: Take another look at your queries

Comment: this won't do much if you have both as min-width

Comment: Sorry forgot to change

Comment: This requires you to always match the `display` property to that of the element being overridden for the case when the element is shown. Why redeclare `display: inline-block`?

Comment: Although the bootstrap example is more simple, I believe I won't be able to use this. Thank you to all that answered and took the time to explain, however.

Comment: @kapantzak I'm having problems with the formatting now. Would you mind giving it a look? For some reason it's not showing the icons now - just the text!

Comment: @OliSmart Have a look at the example at my answer (Edit). Resize the window and the text will be hidden and the icon will be shown

Answer (score 3):

Using a framework such as Bootstrap will help you do this rather quickly, although the concept is the same with simple css. make two menus (main-menu and responsive menu) and hide one. Then switch the hidden class at a specific width. The great about Bootstrap is that the JQuery is already written by simply using the classes `hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg`

See the **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNPpvv)**

Comment: I like this one. I'm not very familiar with HTML as I've only just started this module at University. Is this method compatible with all browsers?

Comment: Absolutely Sir! Go to http://getbootstrap.com/ and follow the instructions on how to load bootstrap in your system, how to use the classes and different components, and stay close to Stack Overflow, as you will have questions to get you setup

Answer (score 2):

I would use a media query on the 640px and change the background image of the links. Without seeing your html I can't give an exact answer but if you're using a nav with a's inside it would be something as simple as:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    nav a {
        background: url('path/to/image.jpg') no-repeat center center;
        height: 100px;                        /* be sure to set height & width */
        width:  600px;

        /* Hide the text. */
        text-indent: 100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, you can implement this using pure CSS. Just use two media queries:

- One that makes text show up and makes the icons hidden
- Another one for the reverse

Consider this typical and easy example:

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
    /*applied if browser window width is less than or equal to 600px*/
    .text {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 641px) {
    /*applied if browser window width is greater than 600px*/
    .icons {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

If you put these after the initial style declarations for these elements, they will elegantly overwrite them when the above conditions are met, without the need of changing anything in your previous CSS. If you wish to include these queries earlier in the stylesheet, you might use the `!important` keyword.